# How can I get frames from multiple IP cameras?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, multiprocessing, pysimplegui

I am trying to get 8 different frame from 8 different IP Camera(or phone). I tried a lot of thing. I tried cctv viewer, vlc library and opencv to get frames. However a problem occured every time. But my biggest problem is fps. Every camera drop fps. For example I can get 30 fps for 1 camera, 15 fps for 2 camera, 7 fps for 4 camera. So I decided to use multiprocess to solve this problem. I want to use 2 camera for every process. Let me explain with code:

```
sg.theme('DarkBlue')

manager2 = Manager()
camera_3_4 = manager2.Value(ctypes.Array, [])
counter_lock2 = manager2.Lock()  # pylint: disable=no-member

manager3 = Manager()
camera_5_6 = manager3.Value(ctypes.Array, [])
counter_lock3 = manager3.Lock()

manager4 = Manager()
camera_7_8 = manager4.Value(ctypes.Array, [])
counter_lock4 = manager4.Lock()

def camera3andcamera4(camera_3_4):
    try:
        cap3 = WebcamVideoStream(src="http://192.168.1.1:8080/video").start()
        cap4 = WebcamVideoStream(src="http://192.168.1.2:8080/video").start()

        while True:

            frameA = cap3.read()
            frameB = cap4.read()
    
            camera_3_4.value = [frameA, frameB]
                        
    except:
        pass

def camera5andcamera6(camera_5_6):
    try:
        cap5 = WebcamVideoStream(src="http://192.168.1.3:8080/video").start()
        cap6 = WebcamVideoStream(src="http://192.168.1.4:8080/video").start()

        while True:

            frameA = cap5.read()
            frameB = cap6.read()
    
            camera_5_6.value = [frameA, frameB]
                        
    except:
        pass

def camera7andcamera8(camera_7_8):
    try:
        cap7 = WebcamVideoStream(src="http://192.168.1.5:8080/video").start()
        cap8 = WebcamVideoStream(src="http://192.168.1.6:8080/video").start()

        while True:

            frameA = cap7.read()
            frameB = cap8.read()
    
            camera_7_8.value = [frameA, frameB]
                        
    except:
        pass
```

I defined 3 global variables which names are camera_3_4, camera_5_6 and camera_7_8. After that I defined 3 function. I defined 2 camera in every function.

```
def ProjectMain(camera_3_4, camera_5_6, camera_7_8):

    col1 = [[sg.Image(filename='', key='image0',  size=(350, 240))],
        [sg.Text('Kamera 1 Durumu:', justification='left', size=(30, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 10), key='Text0')]]
    col2 = [[sg.Image(filename='', key='image1',  size=(350, 240))],
        [sg.Text('Kamera 2 Durumu :', justification='left', size=(30, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 10), key='Text1')]]
    col3 = [[sg.Image(filename='', key='image2',  size=(350, 240))],
        [sg.Text('Kamera 3 Durumu:', justification='left', size=(30, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 10), key='Text2')]]
    col4 = [[sg.Image(filename='', key='image3',  size=(350, 240))],
        [sg.Text('Kamera 4 Durumu:', justification='left', size=(30, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 10), key='Text3')]]
    col5 = [[sg.Image(filename='', key='image4',  size=(350, 240))],
        [sg.Text('Kamera 5 Durumu:', justification='left', size=(30, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 10), key='Text4')]]
    col6 = [[sg.Image(filename='', key='image5',  size=(350, 240))],
        [sg.Text('Kamera 6 Durumu:', justification='left', size=(30, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 10), key='Text5')]]
    col7 = [[sg.Image(filename='', key='image6',  size=(350, 240))],
        [sg.Text('Kamera 7 Durumu:', justification='left', size=(30, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 10), key='Text6')]]
    col8 = [[sg.Image(filename='', key='image7',  size=(350, 240))],
        [sg.Text('Kamera 8 Durumu:', justification='left', size=(30, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 10), key='Text7')]]
    col9 = [[sg.Image(filename='', key='image8',  size=(350, 240))],
        [sg.Text('Kamera 9 Durumu:', justification='left', size=(30, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 10), key='Text8')]]
    col10 = [
    [sg.Text('Aktif Kamera Sayısı:', justification='left', size=(50, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 20), key='Text10')],
    [sg.Text('Dolu İstasyon Sayısı:', justification='left', size=(50, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 20), key='Text11')],
    [sg.Text('Kamera 1 Müşteri Durumu:', justification='left', size=(50, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 19),
             key='Text12')],
    [sg.ProgressBar(75, orientation='h', size=(35, 20), border_width=4, bar_color=("Red", "Green"), key='progbar1')],
    [sg.Text('Kamera 2 Müşteri Durumu:', justification='left', size=(50, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 19),
             key='Text13')],
    [sg.ProgressBar(75, orientation='h', size=(35, 20), border_width=4, bar_color=("Green", "Red"), key='progbar2')],
    [sg.Text('Kamera 3 Müşteri Durumu:', justification='left', size=(50, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 19),
             key='Text14')],
    [sg.ProgressBar(75, orientation='h', size=(35, 20), border_width=4, bar_color=("Green", "Red"), key='progbar3')],
    [sg.Text('Kamera 4 Müşteri Durumu:', justification='left', size=(50, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 19),
             key='Text15')],
    [sg.ProgressBar(75, orientation='h', size=(35, 20), border_width=4, bar_color=("Red", "Green"), key='progbar4')],
    [sg.Text('Kamera 5 Müşteri Durumu:', justification='left', size=(50, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 19),
             key='Text16')],
    [sg.ProgressBar(75, orientation='h', size=(35, 20), border_width=4, bar_color=("Green", "Red"), key='progbar5')],
    [sg.Text('Kamera 6 Müşteri Durumu:', justification='left', size=(50, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 19),
             key='Text17')],
    [sg.ProgressBar(75, orientation='h', size=(35, 20), border_width=4, bar_color=("Green", "Red"), key='progbar6')],
    [sg.Text('Kamera 7 Müşteri Durumu:', justification='left', size=(50, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 19),
             key='Text18')],
    [sg.ProgressBar(75, orientation='h', size=(35, 20), border_width=4, bar_color=("Green", "Red"), key='progbar7')],
    [sg.Text('Kamera 8 Müşteri Durumu:', justification='left', size=(50, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 19),
             key='Text19')],
    [sg.ProgressBar(75, orientation='h', size=(35, 20), border_width=4, bar_color=("Red", "Green"), key='progbar8')],
    [sg.Text('Kamera 9 Müşteri Durumu:', justification='left', size=(50, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 19),
             key='Text20')],
    [sg.ProgressBar(75, orientation='h', size=(35, 20), border_width=4, bar_color=("Green", "Red"), key='progbar9')]]

    column1_1 = [[sg.Frame(layout=col1, title=''), sg.Frame(layout=col2, title=''), sg.Frame(layout=col3, title='')],
             [sg.Frame(layout=col4, title=''), sg.Frame(layout=col5, title=''), sg.Frame(layout=col6, title='')],
             [sg.Frame(layout=col7, title=''), sg.Frame(layout=col8, title=''), sg.Frame(layout=col9, title='')]]

    column1_2 = [[sg.Column(col10, element_justification='c')]]

    layout = [[sg.Frame(layout=column1_1, title=''), sg.Frame(layout=column1_2, title='')]]

    window = sg.Window("İstasyon Kontrol", layout).Finalize()
    window.Maximize()

    cap1 = WebcamVideoStream(src=0).start()
    cap2 = WebcamVideoStream(src="http://192.168.1.8:8080/video").start()

#------------ The Event Loop ------------#
    while True:
        try:
            event, values = window.read(timeout=1)  # run with a timeout so that current location can be updated

            frameA = cap1.read()
            image_np1 = cv2.resize(frameA, (350, 240)) #Camera 1
            # read frames from stream1

            frameB = cap2.read()
            image_np2 = cv2.resize(frameB, (350, 240)) #Camera 2
            # read frames from stream2

            camera_3_4_List = camera_3_4.value[:]
            image_np3 = cv2.resize(camera_3_4_List[0], (350, 240)) #Camera 3
            image_np4 = cv2.resize(camera_3_4_List[1], (350, 240)) #Camera 4

            camera_5_6_List = camera_5_6.value[:]
            image_np5 = cv2.resize(camera_5_6_List[0], (350, 240)) #Camera 5
            image_np6 = cv2.resize(camera_5_6_List[1], (350, 240)) #Camera 6
        
            camera_7_8_List = camera_7_8.value[:]
            image_np7 = cv2.resize(camera_7_8_List[0], (350, 240)) #Camera 7
            image_np8 = cv2.resize(camera_7_8_List[1], (350, 240)) #Camera 8
        
            imgbytes = cv2.imencode('.png', image_np1)[1].tobytes()
            imgbytes2 = cv2.imencode('.png', image_np2)[1].tobytes()
            imgbytes3 = cv2.imencode('.png', image_np3)[1].tobytes()
            imgbytes4 = cv2.imencode('.png', image_np4)[1].tobytes()
            imgbytes5 = cv2.imencode('.png', image_np5)[1].tobytes()
            imgbytes6 = cv2.imencode('.png', image_np6)[1].tobytes()
            imgbytes7 = cv2.imencode('.png', image_np7)[1].tobytes()
            imgbytes8 = cv2.imencode('.png', image_np8)[1].tobytes()

            window['image0'].update(data=imgbytes)
            window['image1'].update(data=imgbytes2)
            window['image2'].update(data=imgbytes3)
            window['image3'].update(data=imgbytes4)
            window['image4'].update(data=imgbyte5)
            window['image5'].update(data=imgbytes6)
            window['image6'].update(data=imgbytes7)
            window['image7'].update(data=imgbytes8)

            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            # check for 'q' key-press
            if key == ord("q") or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                # if 'q' key-pressed break out
                break

            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            # close output window

        except:
            pass

    window.close()
```

I uptaded 8 pysimplegui image element by using 8 camera output. (2 camera in main process, other 6 camera in 3 different process.)

```
def smap(f):
    return f()

def main():
    f_camera1andcamera2 = functools.partial(ProjectMain, camera_3_4)
    f_camera3andcamera4 = functools.partial(camera3andcamera4, camera_3_4)
    f_camera5andcamera6 = functools.partial(camera5andcamera6, camera_5_6)
    f_camera7andcamera8 = functools.partial(camera7andcamera8, camera_7_8)

    with Pool() as pool:
        res = pool.map(smap, [f_camera1andcamera2, f_camera3andcamera4, f_camera5andcamera6, f_camera7andcamera8])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I defined a pool. As a result, I can get good fps from the first 2 camera. However other cameras fps are too low and there are random delays. For example camera 3 delay is 15 sn, camera 4 delay is 3 second. The first 2 camera doesn't effect even I use 4 or more camera. Actually I want this. Every camera pair have to work together but don't effect other pairs. How can I do this? Is there a mistake about using multiprocess? Or is there a another way to get multiple camera(at least 4 camera) with good fps. Thank you.

Comment: Just a general feedback on the code; `except: pass` should never be used. They mask actual issues with the code, and can be extremely hard to debug in the future. Please use very specific exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will change all of them after find a solution. I used them just for now.

Comment: What's the bandwidth of each stream and what's the bandwidth of your ethernet adapter? What's the streaming format and encoders?

Comment: Does internet connection speed affect performance? For example, I connect my computer and all phones to the same internet to get images from the cameras of the phones. In this way, I can use it as an IP camera and take the images. Sorry, I don't know what the parameters you mentioned are. How can I check these parameters?

Comment: For example if your cameras are connected by ethernet and they each send 1 gigabit/s you will need a 10 gigabit network adapter and a switch with 10 gigabit uplink to your device. If your network is fast enough to receive all the streams, there still might be a bottleneck in your device, e.g. if you have to decode many h264 streams, since decoding needs some processing ressources.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately there is nothing I can do about it. I receive images from cameras via wireless connection. I guess this affects performance. Do I have a mistake in using multiprocessing? Or can't I improve performance a bit by making changes to the code? Are systems that receive images from many cameras always used with a wired connection?

Comment: you may have  a mistake in using wireless.. you can only send so much data over a given frequency in one location at a time. common consumer grade wifi access points frequently can only handle a few hundred megabits total (even when listed as gigabit), and total wifi bandwidth is usually even more limited (especially for 2.4Ghz wifi)

Comment: I would also shy away from `mp.Pool` for this application. Just use `Process` instead so you have more direct control over program flow.